# How to have a ui-view that it does not refresh automatically ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

To start my application is using 2 ui-view, one for displaying the friendlist, and the other one for the specific view like this :

```
<div class="container-fluid h100">
  <div ui-view class="h100">

  </div>
  <div ui-view="connected">

  </div>
</div>
```

The ui-view connected is displayed when the user is connected to the app.

My problem is when i changed the url, it reloads all the views, including the friendlist. I want to change this way. Any tips ? Maybe i need to recreate the structure of the code.

the state part :

```
.state('homepage', {
  url: '/homepage',
  views: {
    "connected" : {
      templateUrl : './src/friendlist.html',
      controller : 'NavRightController'
    },
    "" : {
      templateUrl : './src/homepage.html',
      controller: 'HomePageController',
    }
  }
})
.state('settings', {
  templateUrl: './src/settings.html',
  controller: 'SettingsController',
  url: '/settings',
  views: {
    "connected" : {
      templateUrl : './src/friendlist.html',
      controller : 'NavRightController'
    },
    "" : {
      templateUrl : './src/homepage.html',
      controller: 'HomePageController',
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: When you change url are you changing to /settings?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should have one `ui-view` directive for each html page and make use of the [Nested views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views) of the [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

In your case you can use the friendlist as the **parent view** and then all the others can be seen as "child views".

Hope this could help you